# Firebase Firestore - Does creating a doc reference and using it later overwrite other docs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As per the Firebase docs, I am getting a doc reference and then setting the document data in Cloud Firestore.

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
   var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();

// later...
   newCityRef.set(data);
```

However, in my app, hundreds of documents can be written simultaneously by different users. Does firebase-firestore ensure that the the doc reference obtained is not re-used for the very next user?

For example: 
User 1 tries to insert a doc so a reference is obtained.
User 2 also tries to insert a doc at the same time. Is it possible User 2 could also get the same reference as User 1 - since User 1 has not completed their operation?

If ifirestire does not handle this, what is the right way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID that you get for `newCityRef` is globally unique and different from the hundreds or thousands of document IDs that are being created simultaneously by you or other clients.

The [documentation states this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) about the reference you get when calling the `.doc()` function without a parameter.

> Get a DocumentReference for the document within the collection at the specified path. If no path is specified, an **automatically-generated unique ID** will be used for the returned DocumentReference.

Each call to `db.collection("cities").doc()` will give you a unique reference to a document. You can try this by calling the function twice and comparing the ID that you get.

As a reference on how the uniqueness of IDs are promised, you can see read the article "[The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)" that was published for Firebase push IDs. The Firestore auto-generated IDs follow the same philosophy (you can see the [source code for the JS SDK here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/util/misc.ts#L23-L35)).

It is safe to say that each user's document reference is unique and you can write documents concurrently up to [the documented limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dennis. I guess I am also trying to understand how firestore knows the reference does not exist during the concurrent writes. More from firestore implementation POV. I couldn't necessarily find documentation where firebase/firestore docs mention the ref is always unique.

Comment: Good point. I've added a link to an article that explains uniqueness of ids and a link to the source code of Firestore SDK's id generation.

Comment: Hi, Alex. The id generator I've seen doesn't make difference on collection or globally. Could you post a link?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
var newCityRef = db.collection("cities").doc();
```

Without passing any parameter to the `doc()` function, it means that you create a unique reference to a document within your `cities` collection. The collisions of ids in this case is incredibly unlikely. That's what the document ids were designed for. So you don't have to be concerned about it.

But note, Firestore document ids must be unique within the same collection. They can be duplicated in other collections or subcollections. You can test this feature yourself.

So please remember, that the built-in generator for unique ids that is used in Firestore when you call CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#add) function or CollectionReference's [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#doc) function without passing any parameters, generates random and highly unpredictable ids, which prevents hitting certain hotspots in the backend infrastructure.

All automatically generated document ids are random, and there is practically no chance of two of them colliding. The client SDK generates a document with 20 characters, each allowing for:

- All lowercase letters
- All uppercase letters
- All digits

So there are a total of (26+26+10)^20 = 7.0e35 possible combinations of possible unique ids and you can/should assume they'll be completely unique.